# Django: Not able to execute Validators instead the Except block execute

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

I'm trying to make an email and password validation using validators in Django. I have my own custom Registration form. I'm just fetching the email and password values from it using a view called 'Register'. Whenever I try to register a new user, the code always runs into the except block, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with validate_email() and validate_password(). Here's my view:

```
def register(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
      return render(request, 'index.html')
  else:
      username = request.POST['username']
      email = request.POST['email']
      pass1 = request.POST['password1']
      pass2 = request.POST['password2']
      try:
        validate_email(email)
      except ValidationError:
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'emailErr':'Hmm.. Did you enter a valid email?'})
      try:
        validate_password(pass1)
        validate_password(pass2)
      except ValidationError: #This block runs
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'passErr':'Please enter a valid password'})
      if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
          return render(request, 'register.html', {'error1':'Email already exists'})
      else:
          if pass1 == pass2:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=pass1, email=email)
                user.save()
                login(request,user)
                sendConfirm(user)
                return render(request, 'confirm_please.html')
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'register.html', {'error2':'User already exists'})
          else:
            return render(request, 'register.html', {'error3':'Make sure the passwords are same'})
```

A little help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, your password simply does not pass validation. Just pass the correct error to the user instead of:

> 'Please enter a valid password'

Try this instead:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password

def register(request):
    ...
    try:
        validate_password(pass1)
        validate_password(pass2)
    except ValidationError as err:
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'passErr':'; '.join(err.messages)})
    ...
```

Comment: What's ```.join(err.messages)``` for?

Comment: Nvm I fixed it :)

Comment: @Fanceh, `err.messages` returns a `list`. So you can use `join` to convert it to `string`.

Comment: I see, thanks for reading throughout my code and for the extra knowledge! :D

Answer (score 0):

The code is running up and right, it's validate_password that makes an exception because it asks for an 8 digit password. Thanks for reading! :)